# Identify a short story starring a holographic prison warden on a planet where the inmates have taken over

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in a science fiction anthology a few years ago (say ~2008), but I have no idea when it was published. The story revolves around "The Warden," a hologram/AI who was designed to control a prison planet. Here are all the details I remember:

- The prison planet was named after some historical place, possibly the Bastille, and it had a moon whose name was related to this place. I think the moon had a feminine name.
- The inmates had taken over the prison several years ago. A very cruel woman controlled the prison. I think she ran some kind of drug cartel or something.
- The Warden was programmed to keep the prisoners, well, imprisoned, but he was unable to act because the woman possessed a computer virus that would erase him if he acted against her.
- At some point, a young boy crash-lands on the planet. This is significant.
- The planet has a highly poisonous atmosphere.

Minor spoiler:

> - Somehow the Warden kills the woman; I believe it involves the atmosphere. He broke a window or something.

- It ends with some big spoiler about how the warden was created.

I've googled as much as I can, but I can't seem to find it. I remember thinking it was a very good story and I'd very much like to read it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Prisons](https://web.archive.org/web/20140706170507/http://www.baenebooks.com/p-2141-prisons.aspx) by Kevin J. Anderson & Doug Beason

Some excerpts:

> I am still called the Warden. The prisoners consider it an ironic
> jest.
>
> Barely a meter square, the forcewalls form the boundaries of my
> holographic body. Once this felt like a throne, an isolated position
> from which I could control the workings of Bastille. Now, though, I
> must look out and watch my former prisoners laughing at me.
>
> (...)
>
> Theowane comes to taunt me every day, to gloat over her triumph. She
> paces up and down the corridor outside the forcewalls. To me, she is
> flaunting her freedom to go where she wishes. I do not think it is
> unintentional.
>
> At the time of the revolt, Theowane used her computer skills to
> introduce a worm program that rewrote the control links around my
> Personality, leaving me isolated and helpless. If I attempt to regain
> control, the worm will delete my existence.
>
> (...)
>
> A dime-sized glare shows the distant sun, too far away to heat the
> planet to any comfortable temperature; but overhead, dominating the
> sky, rides the cinnamon-colored moon Antoinette, so close to Bastille
> and so nearly the same size that it keeps the planet heated by tidal
> flexing.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much.

Comment: **Why** is this the correct answer?

Comment: @Wikis Because this is indeed the story I was trying to find. It was a story identification question. This answer identified the story.

Comment: Added some excerpts to elaborate, which I assume is what Wikis was getting at.